# JQuery toggle class not working properly

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am trying to trying to change the class on my accordian if it is open but it goes haywire if you click on one of the other toggle links, the open class toggles according to the other action

Js code is

```
$(function () {
    var $subs = $('li.expanded > ul').hide();

    $('li.expanded > a').click(function (e) {
        var $ub = $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
        $subs.not($ub).slideUp();

       if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
           $(this).removeClass('open');
       } else {
        $(this).addClass('open');
            return false;  
       }


         e.preventDefault();
    });



});
```

and fiddle is

http://jsfiddle.net/r7P43/3/

Comment: Seems to be working in your fiddle for me. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: when you click heading two it adds the class but when you click heading three it does not remove the class from heading two.  The open class should only be there if the nested ul is visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing class only from the currently clicked accordion. You need to remove from all.
Try this:

```
$('li.expanded > a').click(function (e) {
    var $ub = $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle(400, function(){
        $('li.expanded > a').removeClass('open');
        if($ub.is(':visible')){
           $(this).prev('a').addClass('open');
        }
    });
    $subs.not($ub).slideUp();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: that doesn't remove the class when you click the same link only when you click the second toggle link